# chart-js-2 библиотека, отображение всплывающих tooltips

Tags: chart.js

Выводится несколько графиков-линий, требуется выводить подсказки сразу для всех линий при наведении по оси Х (как на рисунке). Как свойство называется, кто применял данную методику?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Свойство режима всплывающих описаний - options.interaction.mode, чтобы отображать информацию для всех графиков, имеющих конкретную x-координату, надо установить это свойство в значение "x":

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        interaction: {
            mode: 'x'
        }
    }
});
```

Описание всех параметров tooltip:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Описание interaction.mode:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#modes

Comment: спасибо, работает!